# Android Studio ScrollView only show visible images

Tags: java, android-studio, scrollview

I've created a scrollview that scrolls through images, but even if some of the images aren't visible it still scrolls as if they were. Is there a way to make the scroll only scroll through the visible images?

Comment: Make sure you only use the [tag:android-studio] tag for questions relating to Android Studio, otherwise you won't necessarily be able to reach the correct people to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following line in imageview xml

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Then the full code like this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

As well as you can also do that with programmatically .

```
ImageView imageview = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Hope you helpful.

Comment: Wow. Yep I was being really stupid. That worked perfectly thank you!

Comment: @jsinclairevans You are welcome & Happy Coding!